# JPEG compression and decompression over and over again

Tags: matlab, jpeg, dct

I'm fairly new to Matlab and image and signal processing. What I have so far is that I'm able to read in an image and perform a DCT conversion and fill this into a matrix and then reconstruct an image by placing low to higher DCT coefficients (5, 10, 15, 30)  and performing an inverse DCT to get this figure --->
[image]

What I am wondering is how can I re-compress the reconstructed images to perform another transform to show further JPEG loss? How would I go about it? Thanks and I hope you will be patient with my explanation of what I'm doing/trying to do as I am quite new to this fantastic world!

Comment: Ignoring numerical inaccuracies in the DCT and inverse DCT calculations, there should be no further loss.  Once you've quantized and dequantized once, quantizing again should give you the same coefficients.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply, is there a way of completing a compress-decompress cycle more than once for the original image and then showing the coefficients?! Would that work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should make a function to do the compression. If you feed the output in a loop you can continue to compress your image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate... I understand what you mean I'm just not 100% sure how to execute it. I'll give it a try anyways, thanks for the help!